# How to change the text on UINavigationBar backButton item?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I know the label on back button item is always the last view clicked, but how should I go if I want to have "back" text on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue bugs me as well. My hack is to change the title of the view controller in `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewWillDisappear:`, where the latter changes the title to what will appear on the "back" button and the former changes it back to what I want the title of that screen to be. For example,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    myViewController.navigationItem.title = @"My Title";
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    myViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Back";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithTitle:@"Your Title"
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
       target:nil
       action:nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: ok but this makes the back button labeled back but when i go back to the last view the 'back' is the text i am seeing on the Title of Navigation bar

Comment: Set the title back to what you want in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @ Legolas has it goes to **rootViewController**?